# Should I use an object or type as trait?

Tags: c++, template, template-meta-programming

**Edit:** Disclaimer: I am new to templates and traits.
I apologize in advance if this is a bad question.

I am refactoring two similar classes with small differences strewn all over them into one template class (or I am trying to anyway).
This is something I just wrote. (I hope I didn't make any mistakes renaming everything.)

```
// declaration - empty
template <typename SETTINGS>
struct SettingsTraits;

// specialization for type CFoo
template <>
struct SettingsTraits<CFoo>
{
  typedef CFooRelated RelatedType;
  typedef CAttribute<CFooRelated > & (CDataSource::*AttrGetter)();
  static CAttribute<CFooRelated > & (CDataSource::*GetAttr)();
};

SettingsTraits<CFoo>::AttrGetter SettingsTraits<CFoo>::GetAttr = &CDataSource::GetFooAttr;

// specialization for type CBar    
template <>
struct SettingsTraits<CBar>
{
  typedef CBarRelated RelatedType;
  typedef CAttribute<CBarRelated> & (CDataSource::*AttrGetter)();
  static CAttribute<CBarRelated> & (CDataSource::*GetAttr)();
};

SettingsTraits<CBar>::AttrGetter SettingsTraits<CBar>::GetAttr = &CDataSource::GetBarAttr;
```

So that I can write something like this

```
CAttribute<SettingsTraits<SETTINGS>::RelatedType> attr = (datasource.*SettingsTraits<SETTINGS>::GetAttr)();
```

But now I am wondering if I shouldn't just have created two different structs and passed those as template parameters instead.

I imagine the calling code would end up looking like this:

```
CAttribute<FooTraits::RelatedType> attr = FooTraits::GetAttr(datasource);
```

So probably somewhat cleaner but I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will actually work.
(I should probably replace the function pointer with a simple one line function that calls the appropriate function for each type in any case.)

Which alternative should I chose? What are the benefits/drawbacks of each?

Does it even make sense to have functions in traits? Should I maybe just use free template functions instead?

Comment: Do you think you could prepare a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) (at minimum, something that can be compiled with an [on-line compiler](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/online-c-compilers))? This way it may become easier to compare and illustrate the trade-offs involved in your choices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `std` way of doing things in C++ would be to provide static member functions of your traits type. Consider:

```
// declaration - empty
template <typename SETTINGS>
struct SettingsTraits;

// specialization for type CFoo
template <>
struct SettingsTraits<CFoo>
{
  typedef CFooRelated RelatedType;
  static CAttribute<RelatedType>& GetAttrFrom(CDataSource& ds) { return ds.GetFooAttr(); }
};

// specialization for type CBar    
template <>
struct SettingsTraits<CBar>
{
  typedef CBarRelated RelatedType;
  static CAttribute<RelatedType>& GetAttrFrom(CDataSource& ds) { return ds.GetBarAttr(); }
};

typedef SettingsTraits<SETTINGS> TRAITS;
CAttribute<TRAITS::RelatedType> attr = TRAITS::GetAttrFrom(datasource);
```

Notice that this way of doing things doesn't involve global *objects* or *values* at all; it's all done entirely within the type system. The compiler can look at the line `TRAITS::GetAttrFrom(datasource)` and statically know that it's equivalent to `datasource.GetFooAttr()`, which means the whole thing compiles down to a single `call` instruction. Your old code would have required a trip to memory in order to load the value of the pointer `SettingsTraits<CFoo>::GetAttr`.

Rule of thumb: you should never need to *construct* a type-traits object at all. If you do, you're probably doing it wrong.